# Unity having trouble opening projects on NAS

Tags: unity-game-engine, nas, local-network

I'm trying to move my Unity project onto a NAS so I can edit it from any laptop in my house. I copied this project from my C drive.

The first NAS I copied the project to is a D-Link, called HOMEONE. The project was located at "\HOMEONE\Volume_2\Unity\My Project\". When trying to open with Unity I get a "Unity Package Manager Error" saying it cannot locate "C:\HOMEONE\Volume_2\Unity\My Project\Packages\manifest.json". This is incorrect because it's assumed the network location is a folder on my C drive. I have not found a way around this yet.

The second NAS I copied the project to is a Synology, called HOMETWO. The project was located at "\HOMETWO\Backups\Programming\My Project\". When I try and open the project on Windows 10, Unity creates a new empty project at "\HOMETWO\Backups\HOMETWO\Backups\Programming\My Project\". This is incredibly weird, I just don't know what to say. When trying to open on Mac Mojave I get the message "The project is on a case sensitive file system. Case sensitive file systems are not supported at the moment". Incredibly frustrating because case sensitive file systems are clearly supported on the Windows and Linux distributions of Unity.

I am surprised at how poorly Unity fared in every one of my attempts. I really thought this would have been handled easily. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: I know nothing about NAS or what a D-Link does exactly ... is it possible to make it a NetworkDrive so it actually gets a real Drive letter? Than there shouldn't be such issues... (https://support.microsoft.com/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive)

Comment: In your first attempt it looks like Windows interpreted your path as a relative one and not absolute. Your path should be "\\HOMEONE\Volume_2\Unity\My Project" , instead you got "\HOMEONE\Volume_2\Unity\My Project". Note the "\\" and "\".
I would start with @derHugo's suggestion and if that does't work I would reccomend you use some sort of VCS to circumvent this issue altogether.